# asp.net rdlc report

Tags: sql, asp.net, rdlc

RDLC row problems,
dynamic column from database, 
rows are not in adequate.

RDLC report is as follows.

```
col1   col2   col3
AA
BB
        CC 
               DD
EE
```

I want to arrange like this.

```
col1   col2   col3
AA      CC     DD
BB
EE
```

Do I need to change some codes in sql?
thanks for help.

SELECT 
    TBL1.FullName AS StaffName,
   EducationInfo.Description AS Description

FROM TBL1
   INNER JOIN Qualification ON  Qualification.StaffID = TBL1.StaffID
   INNER JOIN QualificationItem ON QualificationItem.QualificationID = Qualification.QualificationID
   INNER JOIN EducationInfo ON EducationInfo.EducationID = QualificationItem.EducationID

WHERE QualificationItem.Active=1 AND Staff.Active = 1

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  What does the query have to do with the question?  The data seems to refer to a single table or result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot and repivot unsing aggregation:

```
select max(case when which = 1 then col end) as col1,
       max(case when which = 2 then col end) as col2,
       max(case when which = 3 then col end) as col3       
from (select col, which, row_number() over (partition by which order by ordcol) as seqnum
      from ((select col1 as col, 1 as which, ? as ordcol from rldc) union all
            (select col2 as col, 2 as which, ? as ordcol from rldc) union all
            (select col3 as col, 3 as which, ? as ordcol from rldc) 
           ) r
      where col is not null
     )
group by seqnum;
```

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You seem to assume that order is preserved in your values.  That is not a reasonable assumption.  The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.